# JavaScript keep image change in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background image of a container by setting CSS rules with Javascript on a button click.

This works, but the image changes back almost immediately. Is there any way to keep the changes?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="knoppen">
    <div class="roundbutton" onclick="ImageChange1();" style="background-image:url(Image_Thumb.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
      <a href="" class="buttonlink"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="roundbutton" onclick="ImageChange2();" style="background-image:url(.png); background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
      <a href="" class="buttonlink"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="roundbutton" onclick="ImageChange3();" style="background-image:url(.png); background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
      <a href="" class="buttonlink"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="roundbutton" onclick="ImageChange4();" style="background-image:url(.png); background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
      <a href="" class="buttonlink"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="roundbutton" onclick="ImageChange5();" style="background-image:url(.png); background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
      <a href="" class="buttonlink"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
function ImageChange1() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = "url('Image1.jpg')";
}

function ImageChange2() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = "url('Image2.jpg')";
}

function ImageChange3() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = "url('Image1.jpg')";
}

function ImageChange4() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = "url('Image1.jpg')";
}

function ImageChange5() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = "url('Image1.jpg')";
}
```

Comment: It works? That's a miracle, because I don't see any element with the id `#container` here. And it does not "change back", it reloads the page because you clicked on a link. To prevent that, add `return false;` at the end of each function (which could be turned in one single function, by the way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly: that is almost impossible to work, since there is no `container` div.
Secondly: you do not need four different functions to make it work. Just make one like this:

```
function changeBackgroundImage(id){ 
   var d = document.getElementById("container"); 
   d.className = "image"+id;
}
```

Now you can just call it in your HTML by doing this:
`onclick="changeBackgroundImage(idofyourtype); return false;"`

Then add a new CSS class which contains the image like this:

```
#container.image1{
 background-image: url('pathtoimage');
}
```

etc..

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogJMgp)

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you very much. And sorry, I left out the container div.

Comment: But there seems to be a issue where the images seem to be placed on top of each other and you can't change back to previous images.

Comment: What exactly did you change? I tried your code again and tried to edit it myself, but it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler alternative:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    buttons   = document.getElementsByClassName('roundbutton');

for(var i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l; i++ ){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', changeImage);
}

function changeImage(){
    var url = this.getAttribute('data-img');
    container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')';
}
```

```css
/* Just some styles for the demo */ #knoppen{padding:.5em;background:#ededff;text-align:center}.roundbutton{border-radius:.2em;padding:1em 1.5em;margin:.2em .5em;background:center #bbb;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;background-size:cover;-webkit-transition:all .2s;-moz-transition:all .2s;transition:all .2s}.roundbutton:nth-child(1){background-image:url(http://tiny.cc/5iluvx)}.roundbutton:nth-child(2){background-image:url(http://tiny.cc/sjluvx)}.roundbutton:nth-child(3){background-image:url(http://tiny.cc/5jluvx)}.roundbutton:nth-child(4){background-image:url(http://tiny.cc/hkluvx)}.roundbutton:hover{-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);-moz-transform:scale(1.2);transform:scale(1.2);box-shadow:0 0 0 .12em #f24e0d}#container{width:15.8em;margin:0 auto;height:7em;background:url(http://tiny.cc/5iluvx) center #bbb;background-size:cover;border-radius:.2em}
```

```html
<div id="knoppen">
    <div class="roundbutton" data-img="http://tiny.cc/5iluvx"></div>
    <div class="roundbutton" data-img="http://tiny.cc/sjluvx"></div>
    <div class="roundbutton" data-img="http://tiny.cc/5jluvx"></div>
    <div class="roundbutton" data-img="http://tiny.cc/hkluvx"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Here, I'm using an attribute `data-img` that contains the url of the image.
Try it by clicking the blue button. Note that I removed the CSS from the HTML to make the code easier to read (you don't have to) and I removed the links (do you need them?).